# Delete multiple images from Imgur

Tags: node.js, express, imgur

I'm trying to delete multiple images from imgur via a `POST` request, but it's not working for some reason and I'm getting no error messages.

Here's the basic code inside the `POST`:

```
const imgur = require('imgur');
var delete_count = 0;

array_of_deletehashes.forEach(deletehash => {
      imgur
        .deleteImage(deletehash)
        .then((status) => {
          delete_count += 1;
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.error(err.message);
        });
    });
    console.log(delete_count + " images deleted of " + array_of_deletehashes.length)
    //always get 0 of X
```

I tried changing it to `PUT` and that didn't work either. I was able to delete a single image in a different part of my code, not sure why this isn't working.

Any thoughts?

Comment: use a normal for loop with async/await, your .then code won't update delete_count until its finished, which will happen after console.log'ing

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Would forEach affect the image getting deleted on Imgur though? Because the image isn't being deleted at all - I can still see it at the link imgur gives you. Will try out a normal for loop too, thanks.

Comment: no it wouldn't, but; the solution wouldn't involve a forEach because you would need to put async on the callback function which you shouldn't